# How do Madhwas explain Taittiriya Upanishad 2.1.1?

Tags: vedanta, upanishads, dvaita, madhwa, taittirya-upanishad

Madhwas hold that Akasha was not created and it was eternally present.

But [Taittiriya Upanishad, Brahmananda Valli, First Shloka](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-taittiriya-upanishad/d/doc79803.html) (2.1.1) says

> तस्मा॒द्वा ए॒तस्मा॑**दा॒त्मन॑ आका॒शः सम्भू॑तः** ।
> Tasmadva etasmad**atmana akasas sambhutah**
>
> From Atma Akasha was created.

Edit: [Here](https://www.dnaofhinduism.com/philosophy/philosophy-of-sri-madhvacharya-the-dvaita) is a source I found on internet.

> Space contains everything and makes movement possible. According to
> Madhvacharya, there are two kinds of Akasha (Space) – the
> Avyakritakasa (uncreated eternal and unmodified space), and Akasa
> forming one of the five elements evolved out of Prakriti. Avakritakasa
> are coeval with Brahman like Prakriti and the Jiva.

So do Madhwas consider the Upanishad verse as the creation, not of Avyakritaakasha but of Akasha of Pancha Bhootas?

If so what exactly are these and the difference between Avyakritaakasha and Akasha of the Pancha Bhootas?

Comment: Do you have a reference where Madhva (or another Dvaita acharya) said this?

Comment: Yeah, you have to provide the source where Mādhva or some Dvaitin says that ākāśa is eternally present and not created. Without the source, this question cannot be answered and is incomplete.

Comment: Have added the source @Bingming

Comment: Habe added the source @MassEnquirer